# how to put web scraped data into a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

this is the code I used to get the data from a website with all the wordle possible words, im trying to put them in a list so I can create a wordle clone but I get a weird output when I do this. please help

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tabatkins/wordle-list/main/words"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
word_list = list(soup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It do not need `BeautifulSoup`, simply split the text of the response:

```
import requests

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tabatkins/wordle-list/main/words"
requests.get(url).text.split()
```

Or if you like to do it wit `BeautifulSoup` anyway:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tabatkins/wordle-list/main/words"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.text.split()
```

Output:

```
['women',
'nikau',
'swack',
'feens',
'fyles',
'poled',
'clags',
'starn',...]
```